# Compile kernel gets no error but version doesn't change

Tags: grub2, kernel, compiling, vmware

So I'm trying to compile a linux kernel in Ubuntu 14.04 to change the linux version from 3.16 to 3.14.4 and also to change one thing in config. I followed this [tutorial](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/compiling-linux-kernel-26.html#comment-145427) step by step. Exept Step 6 where I switched `mkinitrd` for `mkinitramfs` as suggested by others. Also Step 7 `# vi /boot/grub/menu.lst` was skipped and I only ran `update-grub`. After all this is done I reboot but when I check my kernel version it still says 3.16.

I use ubuntu in VMware Player and maybe I missed something because this tutorial is from 2008. But a friend of mine working on a similar thing followed this tutorial.

Did I miss something? Isn't it possible to recompile a kernel to an older one?

Comment: Sounds as if your problem is with grub. Depending on the name of your new kernel you should see the kernel to boot in grub. By default I believe grub will boot the highest number kernel.

Comment: Aha, that is true. I could change the kernel to boot in. Thank you!

Comment: You may need to run `sudo update-grub` first before you try to boot this way. Then, select "advanced options" from the grub menu and select the desired kernel from there.